# Fix UV Pole Pinching on an environment sphere?

Tags: uv

The Famous youtuber blender secrets made a video fixing equirectangular pole pinching on normal 3D objects like a moon as shown in the video:

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/s8ZagRMwP7Q

I tried to apply this to the environment itself, and it does not work, the environment texture is still pole pinched.

[image]

I just used this texture for showing the example.

https://stock.adobe.com/images/360-degree-space-background-with-nebula-and-stars-equirectangular-projection-environment-map-hdri-spherical-panorama/266760651

Does anyone know how to fix pole pinching on the environment sphere? Or turn the environment sphere into a cube?